# How to set yearRange on primefaces calendar without preset date?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This works fine when I display a selection with birthday already set:

```
<p:calendar id="german" value="#{listView.selected.birthday}"
    locale="de" yearRange="-100:+0" navigator="true" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
```

But when I create a new entry, it works like it's set to `yearRange="c-10:c+10"`. I'm just wondering as `yearRange="-100:+0"` should not depend on the currently selected date, but on the actual date. I don't want to set a default date, so that without selecting a date the user won't save a wrong birthday.

How can I fix this?

(Primefaces Version: 5.2)

Comment: I tested your code and works fine. The `yearRange` depends on the current date (today, 17/07/2015). I tried with[out] a established birthday date.

Comment: There are two attributes: `mindate` and `maxdate`. Perhaps, these are better to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so stupid of me - I had another file for creation of new entries and forgot to update that. I guess I have to reuse more of the code.